# Asp.net Web Service Could not create type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asmx

I'm trying to create a web service for a website, but I'm receiving a 'Could not create type' error when launching the service from visual studio. I'm out of ideas and I would like to know if you could help me find the issue.

- I am currently using .NET 4.5.1
- I have implemented the AjaxControlToolkit with NuGet Packages
- I have created a proof of concept and it is working fine, but when I'm implementing it on the bigger project, it doesn't work.
- I am using this example: http://forums.asp.net/t/1980226.aspx?+NET+4+5+1+and+AjaxControlToolkit+s+AutoCompleteExtender+working+solution

.asmx (Project name is ESI-AP)

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="InvAutoComplete.asmx.vb" Class="ESI-AP.InvAutoComplete.AutoComplete" %>
```

.asmx.vb

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.WebService

Namespace InvAutoComplete

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(False)> _
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService>
Public Class AutoComplete
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetStates(prefixText As String, count As Integer) As List(Of String)

        Dim statesTemp As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {"Alaska", "Alabama", "California", "North Dakota"}
        Dim states As New List(Of String)

        For Each SingleState As String In statesTemp
            If SingleState.ToLower.Contains(prefixText.ToLower) Then
                states.Add(SingleState)
            End If
        Next

        Return states

    End Function

End Class

End Namespace
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `Class` attribute on the `WebService` directive does not match the class definition in your code behind.

`ESI-AP.InvAutoComplete.AutoComplete` is a *class* called `AutoComplete` inside a *namespace* called `ESI-AP.InvAutoComplete`.

Your code behind defines `InvAutoComplete.AutoComplete`, the *class* is `AutoComplete` (matches the directive), but the *namespace* is `InvAutoComplete`, which is not the same namespace.

Comment: Hi kaveman, good catch! For some reason I didn't post the latest example I had. I've edited my post with the correct namespace. The issue is still happening.

Comment: @Pier-Luc The fact that the project name is `ESI-AP` does not necessarily affect the namespacing. Since you have explicitly said the namespace in your codebehind is `InvAutoComplete`, the namespace in your directive must also be `InvAutoComplete`

Comment: Yes, the class in the directive is currently ESI-AP.InvAutoComplete.AutoComplete

Comment: That's my point. The class in the codebehind is currently `InvAutoComplete.AutoComplete` which is **not the same class**

Comment: Oh ok, I've also try to only put "InvAutoComplete.AutoComplete" in the class, but I still get the error "Could not create type 'InvAutoComplete.AutoComplete'."

In the proof of concept that I've made, I had the Project name, the namespace, and the class, and I didn't cause an error "AutoComplete.AutoCompleteExample.AutoComplete".

Comment: So your directive now says `<%@ WebService ... Class="InvAutoComplete.AutoComplete" %>` and you still get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Fisrtly let me tell you that I'm not a vb.net expert but the premise is the same as C#

I've noticed that the above answer did not work for you. But yes, first of all you need to fix your markup and particularly the **class** attribute on the .asmx file so that it reflects both your namespace(s) and class name, so for the given backend file.

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="InvAutoComplete.asmx.vb" Class="InvAutoComplete.AutoComplete" %>
```

Assuming that your webservice **project** is in the same **solution** as your website what you need to do next is add a reference of the **webservice project** to your **website** so that 'webservice.dll' is inside the bin folder of the website.
Afterwards 'slight trick here' create a folder in your website structure and call it say 'webservices' create a .asmx file in there (no code behind) and add this to the html

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="InvAutoComplete.asmx.vb" Class="InvAutoComplete.AutoComplete" %>
```

Run the website as you would normally and go to http://yourlocalhost:xxxx/webservices/InvAutoComplete.asmx and hopefully that will do the trick.

When deploying into the web server (remotely) remember to create the same file strucutre and every time you want to update the webservice you just need to replace the "webservice.dll" in the bin folder of website.

I hope this helps and best of luck.